# Script working in Fiddle and JSBin but not in Dreamweaver + preview

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a script to change the play button on vimeo vids but it doesn't work in DW's preview in Chrome. Click the play button doesn't do anything. However, it works in jsbin and fiddle? So confused! Below is the exact same code in dreamweaver.

https://jsbin.com/fawowaleci/edit?html,css,output

```
$(function () {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('video');
    var player = $f(iframe);

    player.addEvent('ready', function () {
        player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
    });

    $('.playpause').click(function () {
        player.api('paused', function (paused) {
            if (!paused) {
                player.api('pause');
                $(".playpause").removeClass('pause');
            } else {
                player.api('play');
                $(".playpause").addClass('pause');
            }
        });
    });

    function onFinish(id) {
        $(".playpause").removeClass('pause');
    }
});
```

Comment: What is `$f(iframe)`? Is `$f` a typo for `$`?

Comment: @Barmar Its associated with Froogaloop :) https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api